# Adding a JavaScript embed to HTML

Tags: javascript, html, embed

I am given this code which should display an embedded small coupon version of this page https://weedmaps.com/deals#/1118217:

```
<script type="text/javascript">var coupon_id = 17811;</script>
<script type="text/javascript">var coupon_type = "deliveries";</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://weedmaps.com/embed/coupon.js"></script>
```

I do not know how to add the JavaScript to the HTML correctly. I have placed the following scripts in the head section. But I don't understand how to have the coupon generate in the div I want it to. I have tried calling the JavaScript function, but I've never worked with JavaScript before. Could someone please help me embed this coupon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've taken a look at your script and first of all: it definitely should be placed inside the document and not into the `<head>` section because coupon.js is writing out html at the placement of the coupon.js script import.

In theory you just need to place the script and it should work but there are some problems:

1. You need to execute it on a web server - when running as a plain html file the script just tries to find the libraries in your file system which does not work.
2. It still would not work because it would still try to find some resources at your web-server. In mycase it the script tried to load http://localhost:63342/restpoints/deliveries/17811/deal which will not work
3. To prove 2. just try https://weedmaps.com/restpoints/deliveries/17811/deal with the correct domain. Then you are receiving correct JSON which is used to fill the coupon pane.

=> Consequently the script you were given has problems if it should be executable from domains different from "weedmaps.com"

Answer (score 0):

Javascript can be between head tag but it advisable to put it below before the body closing tag, to allow your page contents loads first before loading javascript. Just import your javascript. and call out. Hope this was helpful.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

</head>
```

var coupon_id = 17811;

Answer (score 0):

The JS indicates it is looking for an element with an id of #weedCouponPane. Do you have this in your html? i.e.

```
<div id="weedCouponPane"></div>
```